# Trying to create standalone Sikuli application

Tags: automation, sikuli, sikuli-script

I want to be able to distribute my Sikuli script and allow the end user to run the script without installing Sikuli, my only problem at this point is not knowing what dependencies Sikuli needs to run (besides JAVA). With this knowledge I simply want to create a zip file for my user's machines that they can unzip into a folder and run the script.

Comment: Copied all Sikuli files from it's native folder on my pc to another folder on my PC as a test, but when running my .skl file using Sikuli-IDE.bat from the command line I get the following errors:
Apr 3, 2016 11:23:21 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.

and a file not found error looking in the appdata folder for my .py file.

Comment: this error does not seem to be interrupt script execution and in some cases can be ignored. Are you certain that the script actually fails at this point? Try to check maybe it is still running after showing this error message.

Comment: Seems to fail at the io error (cannot find app data / myscript.py)

Comment: Ok, I don't understand,  I saved the file under a different name then copied and pasted and it worked perfectly. Going to try pasting the files into a different pc and trying that.

Comment: yeah, like I said I have encountered such error and usually it is not critical and I have been able to continue running the script successfully. Perhaps you have other issue in your code. If you want to be sure that your code fails elsewhere just add few more prints that will identify "where you are" in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using SikuliX as a command line script and not the IDE(*IDE should probably work same way too. but I have not much experience with it*) , you can simply copy the whole SikuliX folder to another PC and it will usually work straight away. As you mentioned yourself, the only requirement is Java.

Comment: Yes, using it as command line script, but tried copying the folder to a different area on my PC as a test but get nothing but errors running it.

Comment: @user1724365 add that information, including the errors, to your question.